Historical Linguistics: The stress of nouns ending in "-fono"
Most Spanish words from Latin keep their stress location on the one from the Latin. But I noticed that all nouns ending in -fono like teléfono are stressed on the third-to-the-last syllable, while -fono comes from Greek -phōnē via New Latin -phōnum, stressed penultimately. Is there any reason for this uncommon stress pattern?

La mayoría de los cultismos que tienen ese tipo de sufijos son palabras esdrújulas. En general, son palabras que aparecieron mucho después del latín, no más que hace uno o dos siglos. Ni siquiera existían en el latín. No veo mucha más ciencia que esa.

@tac Are there any similar examples?

Megáfono, xilófono, audífono, alófono, homófono, anglófono

Tu observación es correcta, pero esto no es tan excepcional.
Toda lengua es hablada en primer lugar y es la lengua hablada la que determina dónde recae el acento. Por eso, en el español hablado en Sudamérica, el acento recae a menudo en una sílaba diferente que en el español hablado en España.
Tampoco se puede comparar el acento en inglés con el acento en español.
Las palabras terminadas en -fono se consideran palabras esdrújulas en español, que según las normas de acentuación del español siempre tienen la sílaba tónica en la antepenúltima sílaba: miércoles, sábado, gramática, pájaro, rápido, y también ... teléfono.
Excepción: La palabra “interfono” es un acrónimo de las palabras francesas “intérieur” y “téléphone”. En francés el acento recae en la penúltima silaba y así se adoptó en la pronunciación española. Por lo tanto, interfono es una palabra llana (o grave).
Un sinónimo en español es citófono, acrónimo de circuito y teléfono.
